# How to extract date from datetime json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json datetime like this `2013-11-09T00:00:00` I want to extract the date from this string  using Jquery or javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The winner is:

```
var date = new Date(
    jsonDate
    .replace("T"," ")
    .replace(/-/g,"/")
);
```

since that is the only one that works in IE AND FX AND Chrome

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HZDyZ/)

```js
var jsonDate = "2013-11-09T00:00:00";
var date = new Date(Date.parse(jsonDate));
console.log("With parse\t\t"+date);
date = new Date(jsonDate);
console.log("Without parse\t\t"+date);
date = new Date(jsonDate.replace("T", " "));
console.log("Without T\t\t"+date);
date = new Date(jsonDate.replace("T", " ").replace(/-/g, "/"));
console.log("Without T and dash\t"+date);

var dayNames = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  pad = function(str) {
    return ("0" + str).slice(-2);
  }

function formatDateStr(dStr) {
  var date = new Date(dStr.replace("T", " ").replace(/-/g, "/"));
  // Sat Nov 09 2013
  return dayNames[date.getDay()] +
    " " + monthNames[date.getMonth()] +
    " " + pad(date.getDate()) +
    " " + date.getFullYear();
}
console.log(formatDateStr("2013-11-09T00:00:00"));
```

```
var jsonDate = "2013-11-09T00:00:00";
```

**1AM in Chrome, NaN in IE8, OK in Fx:**

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(jsonDate));
window.console&&console.log("With parse "+date);
```

---

**1AM in Chrome, NaN in IE8, OK in Fx:**

```
var date = new Date(jsonDate)
window.console&&console.log("Without parse "+date);
```

---

**OK in Chrome, NaN in IE8, Invalid Date in Fx:**

```
date = new Date(jsonDate.replace("T"," "));
window.console&&console.log("Without T "+date);
```

---

**OK in Chrome, OK in IE8, OK in Fx:**

```
date = new Date(jsonDate.replace("T"," ").replace(/-/g,"/"));
window.console&&console.log("Without T and dash "+date);
```

---

UPDATE - formatting:

In Chrome and Fx you may get away with .split(" ") and take the first 4 entries, but in IE you will have `Sat Nov 9 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013` - and toLocaleString gives `11/9/2013 12:00:00 AM` on my box

```
var dayNames  = ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],
    monthNames= ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
    pad=function(str) {return ("0"+str).slice(-2);}
function formatDateStr(dStr) {
  var date = new Date(dStr.replace("T"," ").replace(/-/g,"/"));
  // Sat Nov 09 2013
  return dayNames[date.getDay()]+
     " "+monthNames[date.getMonth()]+
     " "+pad(date.getDate())+
     " "+date.getFullYear();
}
window.console&&console.log(formatDateStr("2013-11-09T00:00:00"));
```

Comment: why are you replacing the "T"?

Comment: You are right.... I think I got confused with something I did a while ago, let me check

Comment: @mplungjan now its perfect.

Comment: I was not confused. I needed to remove T AND the dash

Comment: @mplungjan thank for your answer but string is this :"Sat Nov 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" all i need is "Sat Nov 09 2013"

Comment: If the date is in the format `\/Date(1466654400000-0400)\/`, would this still work?

Comment: Not without a change

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = "2013-11-09T00:00:00";
new Date(Date.parse(d));
```

Comment: Test in more than one browser

Comment: @mplungjan - works in the latest FF and chrome, could you be less cryptic?

Comment: try IE - still a few million IE8 users out there. The Date.Parse is not necessary for the browsers that support the date format, the - dash kills IE. Just read my answer to see what I meant

Comment: @mplungjan - IE8 kudos!